# Adding additional fields to a return from a query in ndb but not working

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, app-engine-ndb

```
courses, next_cursor, more_results = CourseTable.query()\
                                                    .order(CourseTable.name)\
                                                    .fetch_page(2, \
                                                        start_cursor=current_cursor,\
                                    projection=['name', 'abbrev_name'] 

list = format_list(courses) 
logging.info(list)
```

---

```
def format_list(coursequery):

    for x in coursequery:
        keyid = x.key.id()
        x.school_list = ICTable.school_nameabbrev_from_courseid(courseid=keyid)
        x.teacher_list = TCTable.teacherfilter_from_courseid(courseid=keyid)
        x.courseid = keyid
        full_list.append(x)
    return full_list
```

For the above logic, I am doing a projection query in ndb google datastore and then formatting (i.e. format_list) the returned query with extra fields retreived from other entities.  I then append the updated query with the extra fields, but when I do a logging.info display of the list, I do NOT see the added fields (i.e. school_list and teacher_list -- only the fields from the original projection query---ANY BODY have any ideas why???  Thank you so much anyone.

Comment: You are missing code.  what is the scope of `full_list`

Answer (score 2):

I think you should first convert the returned object into dict and then add the additional fields.
you can use this to convert to dict

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/modelclass#Model_to_dict

Comment: ok good idea - will try that - but it did work when I was sending the info from server when rendering the template but it doesn't work when I'm getting the info through async js call - any reason it wouldn't work in async js vs.  direct from server?  makes no sense?

Answer (score 1):

A projection query returns entities intended to be read-only.  An easy workaround would be to convert the data to a dict, as omair says.  Try `d = x._to_dict()`.

It actually is saving the data, but the str method on projections only prints the projected fields.